# What to do when there are multiple answers with only code and zero explanation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answer-quality

This is the question I'm talking about: [Change a variable when button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360486/change-a-variable-when-button-is-clicked).

There are only a couple of answers that have *some* explanation on the code they provided; the rest are simply "here's your answer/try this/this is how I'd to it" type of answers.

What should I do with these answers? Should I just downvote them all and move on? The actual issue is that there are multiple answers and I don't want to go commenting on each one.

Comment: I always try to think a bit ahead, about future visitors of the question and it's answers. If it seems the answer would only feed the OP a fish, instead of teaching them how to fish I seriously consider down voting as such answer are not useful.

Comment: @honk Thanks for the edit, the question was written when there was only one explanatory answer, but later there were more than one.

Comment: @cst1992: You are welcome. If my edit doesn't fully reflect your intention, then please feel free to improve it.